# Change Port using Jenkins-lts Homebrew

Tags: macos, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was wondering how one could change Jenkins-lts default port 8080 on Mac using Homebrew Installation. Actually I have 2 folders one on :

1. /Users/XXXXXX/.jenkins/  In here after execute all the process still runing on Port:8080
2. /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/ In here when I executed the process jenkins running on Port:8383 but any jobs work.

I took the example for other Stack Member Ifeego answered Aug 21 '18 at 8:55, This is what I did:

I have installed Jenkins LTS by brew command:

```
brew install jenkins-lts
```

So my Jenkins plist file is here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.121.2/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
```

You can modify the httpPort value from default 8080 to the other value,and then save the file.

> Label
>       homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts
>       ProgramArguments
>       
>         /usr/libexec/java_home
>         -v
>         1.8
>         --exec
>         java
>         -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
>         -jar
>         /usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/libexec/jenkins.war
>         --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1
>         --httpPort=8383
>       
>       RunAtLoad

`sudo launchctl unload` command will not work for you. You must try these commands to restart your Jenkins and make the port modification works.

After executed the change on jenkins-lts.plist file:

```
brew services stop jenkins-lts
brew services start jenkins-lts
```

> ```
> ifeegoo:~ ifeegoo$ brew services stop jenkins-lts
> Stopping `jenkins-lts`... (might take a while)
> ==> Successfully stopped `jenkins-lts` (label: homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts)
> ifeegoo:~ ifeegoo$ brew services start jenkins-lts
> ==> Successfully started `jenkins-lts` (label: homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts)
> ```

Note:When I open the terminal and run brew services start jenkins-lts jenkins go up using the new Port:8383 in these case they do not run any job, but when I run on the terminal the command: jenkins-lts the application up in the Port:8080 and here I can run all the Jobs without troubles.

Comment: http://regeda.net/2016/07/06/how-to-change-default-port-on-jenkins-from-default-to-custom-on-mac/

Comment: Thank you, but note that 2.121.2 is a variable.  I got https to work by setting --httpsPort and --httpsListenAddress, and disabled http with --httpPort=-1.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
 +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
 |                   MacOS                                         |
 |                                                                 |
 |  +----------------------+   +--------------------------------+  |
 |  | Homebrew Jenkins LTS |   | Legacy Jenkins                 |  |
 |  | Port: 8383           |   | Port: 8080                     |  |
 |  | Home: Undefined      |   | Home: /Users/XXXXXX/.jenkins/  |  |
 |  +----------------------+   +--------------------------------+  |
 +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Following "[Jenkins home path changes by itself after restarting macOS. How do I set up `JENKINS_HOME`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71595505/6309)", you might want to start the Jenkins you want while setting its `JENKINS_HOME` to your existing `/Users/XXXXXX/.jenkins`.

> 1. Edit the file: `/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.jenkins-lts.service`
> 2. Add this Flag Before -jar. `-DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/`.
> 3. Edit the file `/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist` by adding the string parameter:
>
>    ```
>    <string>-DJENKINS_HOME=/Users/myuser/.jenkins</string>
>    ```
> 4. Make sure to pass all of these arguments before the -jar argument

That way:

- you would run your Jenkins LTS with the new port
- but would still get all your Job from your legacy Jenkins