# Jenkins home path changes by itself after restarting MacOS. How do I setup JENKINS_HOME?

Tags: macos, jenkins, homebrew, jenkins-cli

I installed jenkins-lts from Homebrew using this command.

`brew install jenkins-lts`

Installation was succesful. Then, I started Jenkins.

`brew services start jenkins-lts`

which directs me to Unlock Jenkins page. The initial password was contained at

`/Users/myusername/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

I logged in, install plugins and setup an admin account without any problem. However, after I restarted MacOS, Jenkins home path changes by itself to /var/root/.jenkins. It ignores the admin account I created and prompted me to **Unlock Jenkins again** by using the password found here:

`/var/root/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Then I have to redo setting up another admin account.

My question is: Why does this always happen after I restart MacOS (Catalina version 10.15.7)? How do I setup JENKINS_HOME to /Users/myusername/.jenkins ?

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56077446/598141) ?

Comment: I think the link provided by @IanW does not work since that one is for a Mac Installer installation instead of homebrew installation.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/56077446/4696051 "Found the answer but only if you installed using the Mac installer (not brew)."

Answer (score 3):

According with the [Jenkins Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/), it is possible to provide the JENKINS_HOME system properly in the java service such as:

```
-DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/
```

In this case, as you have installed Jenkins with homebrew, the service file should be located at: /usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.jenkins-lts.service

So you can modify the **ExecStart** command and add this and other flags as required.

Summary:

1. Edit the file: `/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.jenkins-lts.service`
2. Add this Flag Before -jar. `-DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/`.
3. Edit the file `/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist` by adding the string parameter:

   -DJENKINS_HOME=/Users/myuser/.jenkins
4. Make sure to pass all of these arguments before the -jar argument

If the previous change didn't worked, alternatively add the `DJENKINS_HOME` string parameter to the plist `/Library/LaunchDaemons/jenkins-lts.plist` in the following manner:

```
<string>-DJENKINS_HOME=/Users/myuser/.jenkins</string>
```

Comment: That's correct, but you might need to launch the right one with this CMD :
/usr/bin/java -jar /tmp/jenkins.war --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0 --httpPort=80